# Query return only one row of data

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Am creating a web app in codeigniter, it retrieves posts from the database for a user based on the keywords they have added to their keyword list.
Am trying to retrieve all the posts with the users keywords but,it returns only one post whereas there are mutliple matches for the keywords in the posts

This is are the functions from my model

This function retrieves the users keywords

```
function user_keywords($user_id) {
         //Get all the user keywords
         $q = $this->db->select('keywords')
                        ->from('keywords')
                        ->where('U_id',$user_id)
                        ->get();
        $words = $q->result_array();
        return $words;
     }
```

This function retrieves the posts

```
function get_latest_pheeds() {
        $this->load->helper('date');
         $time = time();
         $keyword = $this->user_keywords($this->ion_auth->user_id);
         foreach($keyword as $word) {
         $q = $this->db->select('user_id,pheed_id,datetime,pheed,COUNT(pheed_comments.comment_id) as comments')
         ->from('pheeds')
         ->join('pheed_comments','pheed_comments.P_id=pheeds.pheed_id','left')
         ->like('pheed',$word['keywords'])
         ->order_by('datetime','desc')
         ->get();
         }
         $rows = $q->result_array();
         return $rows;
     }
```

And my controller encodes it in JSON

```
function latest_pheeds() {
            if($this->isLogged() == true) {
            $this->load->model('pheed_model');
            $data = $this->pheed_model->get_latest_pheeds();
            echo json_encode($data);
            }
            return false;
    }
```

I really appreciate the help

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't in your select() or result_array() method?

Comment: `$q` in your `get_latest_pheeds()` method will have the last query. Before suggesting a better approach, what `$word['keywords']` contains? a single keyword? also is it exactly the same in the `keywords` table as in the `pheeds` table (in the `pheed` field)?

Comment: $word['keywords'] contains keywords returned from user_keywords() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think (but it is hard without testing) that the problem comes form the function get_last_feeds :

you query is built over each loop's iteration, but you fetch the results after. I think you get the results only for the last query (if you don't fetch the results on each loop, the next iteration overwrites the original request without fetching it's results).

I would make something like this :

```
<?php
function get_latest_pheeds() {
     $rows = array(); // The final result, an array of rows
    $this->load->helper('date');
     $time = time();
     $keyword = $this->user_keywords($this->ion_auth->user_id);
     foreach($keyword as $word) {
     $q = $this->db->select('user_id,pheed_id,datetime,pheed,COUNT(pheed_comments.comment_id) as comments')
     ->from('pheeds')
     ->join('pheed_comments','pheed_comments.P_id=pheeds.pheed_id','left')
     ->like('pheed',$word['keywords'])
     ->order_by('datetime','desc')
     ->get();
     $rows[] = $q->result_array();
     }

     return $rows;
 }
```

Comment: i'll modify the function and try it out